# TeXnicCenter Finnish Spelling, how to use a new language/spelling

Tags: texniccenter, spelling

I am using TeXnicCenter for writing LaTeX documents. Unfortunately, when I am writing in Finnish as I usually do, there is no spell checker in Finnish in TeXnicCenter. All the lines are underlined in red, and this is not nice. I know that there is Voikko for Finnish spell checking in LibreOffice, but is it possible to apply Voikko for TeXnicCenter? TeXnicCenter is using Hunspell; I downloaded the `voikko-laaja.oxt` file but I could not find in this package any files with `.aff` and `.dic` suffices.

Comment: Have you found a finnish dictionary (.dic and .aff) for tex editors?

Comment: People, this question is not a duplicate! Unfortunately there are no .dic and .aff for Finnish because the format is not compatible with the language. I think switching to another editor would be the solution - an editor that relies on a different spell checking system.

Comment: There is http://spell-fi.sourceforge.net for Finnish to get .dic and .aff files and like you said Voikko http://voikko.puimula.org

Answer (score 1):

The file type `.oxt` is an archive. So:

1. Open the file `<filename>.oxt` using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/);
2. Locate the appropriate `.dic` and `.aff` files inside the archive. Typically they are called `<lang>_<dialect>.dic` and `<lang>_<dialect>.aff`;
3. Copy these files to

   ```
   C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\Dictionaries
   ```

   Note that the naming convention is strict. So, if your files have the format `<lang>-<dialect>`, rename them to `<lang>_<dialect>`.
4. (Re)start TeXnicCenter;
5. Identify the new language/dialect from the Tools > Options... > Spelling menu:

   [image]

Comment: I downvoted your answer because, as the question text says, there is no .dic nor .aff file in the .oxt archive for Finnish.